# Sequence file formats in hadoop

Tags: c#, hadoop, sequencefile

Is there any option to write the Hadoop distributed File system files as sequence files using c# code. If so can u suggest me a link or other details

Answer (score 0):

I have not used C# in my Hadoop work, But we can do this.

In JAVA

```
  Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = new Job(conf);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
```

This will write the SequenceFile. Similarly in C# there should be like this

```
  HadoopJobConfiguration myConfig = new HadoopJobConfiguration();

            myConfig.InputPath = "/demo/simple/in";

            myConfig.OutputFolder = "/demo/simple/out";
```

**UPDATED:**

```
 HadoopJobConfiguration myConfig = new HadoopJobConfiguration();

                myConfig.InputPath = "/demo/simple/in";

                myConfig.OutputFolder = "/demo/simple/out";
                myConfig.outputformat  =  // Your needed o/p format
```

Hope this will give you an idea

Comment: thank u for ur reply...I do have that code ..but i want to know whether we can do that in c#

Comment: Did you check that in C#. What have you tried so for then ?

Comment: Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("HADOOP_HOME", @"C:\Hadoop");
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", @"C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_51");
            var config = new HadoopJobConfiguration();
            
            config.InputPath = "/sample.docx";
            config.OutputFolder = "/Count";
            Job job = new Job(config);
            job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
            This is my code and it shows Job cannot be resolved...I know some dlls are missing but I dont know where to find that

Comment: But It doesnt shows any functions such as outputformat